# Eliminate separation between paragraphs

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, vertical-spacing

For a column document I need to use the `\paragraph{}` command as opposed to the common `\par`. Using `\paragraph{}`, however, introduces a space between paragraphs that I do not want (see the image below for said separation).

Since I am not using `\par`, I cannot use `\setlength{\parskip}{0em}` to remove the space between that `\paragraph{}` creates. I know that the simpler solution is not to use it, but it is necessary for what I am doing. I have tried `\vspace{<negative value>}`, but it is janky and depends on factors like word count and such, making it unreliable and unsuitable.

Taking the following code sample, what should be added to remove the highlighted separation and *still continue using* `\paragraph{}` as shown?:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]{\normalfont}{}{}{}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0em}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0em}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\paragraph{A}\lipsum[1]

\paragraph{B}\lipsum[1]

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Remove separation hightlighted in red.]

Comment: despite the name `\paragraph` is really unrelated to paragraphs of text it is the 4th level section heading and should only be used after `\subsubsection` otherwise the document structure (as seen for example `\tableofcontents` will be distorted if you increase secnumdepth.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that, but by chance your comment helped me solve my question and remove the spacing between paragraphs (and sections, which as you say is what they truly are). I will try to work what you said into my document; thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a suitable `\titlespacing` command:

```latex
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]{\normalfont}{}{}{}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{1em}{0pt}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\paragraph{A}\lipsum[1]

\paragraph{B}\lipsum[1]

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your MWE: (1) the `article` class does not provide a `9pt` option and (2) if you included a third paragraph, say C, which would start in the second column then the C interferes with the text in the first column.

If your paragraph titles are all single characters then using `\llap` might give you what you are after:

```
\llap{A} \lipsum[1]

\llap{B} \lipsum[1]
```

However for longer titles `\rlap` would be better:

```
\rlap{Letters} \lipsum[1]
```

Or what about just a simple

```
\textbf{A} \lipsum[1]
```

Comment: Duly noted. (1) The paragraph titles are indeed just single characters, so there is no overlap from the right to the left column; (2) I will take into account what you said about the `article` class, so thank you, sir; and (3), I was looking to get the letter character or label to the left of the paragraph, which the `paragraph{<letter>}` command accomplishes nicely combined with user egreg's answer above. I will take what you said into consideration, that said, and thanks again.